# MS Access: Is there a way to display an asterisk next to certain rows in my printed report?

Tags: ms-access, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a report object I export to PDF (which contains rows from a query), and I want to display an asterisk next to certain rows on the printed PDF (so they can reference a footnote I have in the footer of the report for additional context).

Is there a good way to do this? For example, I want an asterisk next to any row where SomeValue = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your control source to

```
=IIf([yourColumn]=1,[yourColumn] & "*",[yourColumn])
```

Be sure that your textbox is not named the same as your column name. Access does this be default which is really annoying and breaks things like this. Change your textbox name to something like `txtyourColumn`